# Biconomy SDK Response Error when trying to make a transaction on a registered API -> Forwarder domain data is undefined

Tags: ethers.js, meta-transactions, alchemy-sdk

Biconomy SDK Response Error when trying to make a transaction on a registered API -> Forwarder domain data is undefined.

```
const makeTransaction = async () => {
    const provider: any = biconomy!.provider;
    const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract("0x4f6CBcCe9b2908b5dD001d455bD8B1046bB23186", ABI, biconomy.ethersProvider)
    const { data } = await contractInstance.populateTransaction.store("10");
    let txParams = {
      data: data,
      to: "0x4f6CBcCe9b2908b5dD001d455bD8B1046bB23186",
      from: wallets[0],
      signatureType: "EIP712_SIGN",
    };
    provider.send("eth_sendTransaction", [txParams]);
    console.log("COMPLETED");

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Wallets",wallets[0]);
    setTimeout(makeTransaction, 3000);
  }, [wallets])
```

Comment: Hi! Please include some more information. What chain is this being sent to? Where is the `data` coming from? Thanks!